# CDialog child windows

Tags: mfc, move, onpaint, cdialog

I just wanted to use insde of a good old MFC Dialog based application 2 more moveable dialogs as childs. After solution wizard, i made a Default Dialog resource (child style) and created 2 dialogs in OnInitDialog of the main Dialog:

```
m_P1 = new CMyDlg();
m_P2 = new CMyDlg();

m_P1->Create(IDD_DIALOG1, this);
m_P2->Create(IDD_DIALOG1, this);

m_P1->ShowWindow(SW_SHOWNORMAL);
m_P2->ShowWindow(SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Now, they both Show up but when i move them around the redraw of the Client area does not happen. If i overlap both Windows, and pick the one behind in the system bar and start to move it around, the Client area still has Areas which are not updated so they Show Contents of the 2nd overlapping Dialog.

I tried to overwrite OnPaint and invalidate the rectangle there, but as both dialogs are of same class, both dialogs get the OnPaint and both update the full Client area, so there happens a lot of flickering.

I tried to invalidate the Client area only once using ON_WM_ACTIVATE() or ON_WM_SETFOCUS(), but These Events are not called at all.

So what would the correct way to make a moveable child dialog which updates nicely the client area once you drag it around, being in the foreground after selection?

Thx a lot for help

Stefan

Comment: You can make child dialogs inside a main dialog. But I am not sure what you intend to do. It looks like you are trying to make [MDI window](https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC132942.gif) in a dialog. Maybe you can post a link to something that looks like what you want. Also you have to post more code, there is a 1000 different ways to set the flags and create the windows.

Comment: Well using a main dialog is a quick lightweight way for a quick application. However, i tried the same using a SDI Formview, and this behaves much better. The child dialogs render as expected when moving around and overlapping. So a main dialog is indeed not made for this. Thx